# How to get at JSON in grails 2.0

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, grails

I am sending myself JSON like so with jQuery:

```
$.ajax
({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/myproject/myController/myAction',
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  //json object to sent to the authentication url
  data: {"stuff":"yes",
         "listThing":[1,2,3],
         "listObjects":[{"one":"thing"},{"two":"thing2"}]},
  success: function () {
    alert("Thanks!"); 
  }
})
```

I send this to a controller and do

```
println params
```

And I know I'm already in trouble...

```
[stuff:yes, listObjects[1][two]:thing2, listObjects[0][one]:thing, listThing[]:[1, 2, 3], action:myAction, controller:myController]
```

I cannot figure out how to get at most of these values...

I can get "yes" with params.stuff, but I cant do params.listThing.each{} or params.listObjects.each{}

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I make the controller do this to try the two suggestions so far:

```
println params
println params.stuff
println params.list('listObjects')
println params.listThing
def thisWontWork = JSON.parse(params.listThing)
render("omg l2json")
```

look how weird the parameters look at the end of the null pointer exception when I try the answers:

```
[stuff:yes, listObjects[1][two]:thing2, listObjects[0][one]:thing, listThing[]:[1, 2, 3], action:l2json, controller:rateAPI]
yes
[]
null
| Error 2012-03-25 22:16:13,950 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-7] ERROR   errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [POST] /myproject/myController/myAction - parameters:
stuff: yes
listObjects[1][two]: thing2
listObjects[0][one]: thing
listThing[]: 1
listThing[]: 2
listThing[]: 3
```

UPDATE 2 I am learning things, but this can't be right:

```
println params['listThing[]']
println params['listObjects[0][one]']
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 3]
thing
```

<del>It seems like this is some part of grails new JSON marshaling.  This is somewhat inconvenient for my purposes of hacking around with the values.  How would I get all these individual params back into a big groovy object of nested maps and lists?</del>

Maybe I am not doing what I want with jQuery?

UPDATE jQuery was the issue: [Grails: where does request.JSON come from, and how do I put things there with jQuery's .ajax() or .post()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307760/grails-where-does-request-json-come-from-and-how-do-i-put-things-there-with-jq)

Comment: Did you try with `params.list('listObjects')`? That's the proper way of accessing list parameters.

Comment: `println params.list('listObjects')` prints `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if 2.0 has changed this behavior, but in 1.3.7 I used the following to parse JSON data:

```
request.JSON.each {params  ->
...
```

give this a try.

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing it right:  I added that to my controller, and I'm getting the error: `Missing value. at character 0 of .`

Comment: did you complete the closure?

Comment: put the debug at at the top of the action: log.debug("Incoming: "+request.JSON)

Comment: That line crashes with the same error, I'm pretty sure this is grails 2.0 stuff, see my update2.

Comment: This is what I wanted, but jQuery is messing up the call somehow.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sending JSON back to the controller, the best thing for you to do is just have Grails marshel it for you back into your objects.

Note the parseRequest attribute below

```
"/product/$id"(controller: "product", parseRequest: true) {
    action = [GET: "show", PUT: "update", DELETE: "delete", POST: "save"
}
```

Then in your controller it is simple as:

```
def save = {
    def productInstance = new Product(params.product)
}
```

No need to parse your params or anything.  This is of course assuming you can structure your JSON to a Domain.

Comment: This works great, but in this case I actually want to mess around with a big mess of JSON data that isn't one of my domain objects.  Gonna +1, but my problem is actually in the jQuery.

Comment: Make sure you are whitelisting which fields in Product you want to set with params.product.  Otherwise this might be a security flaw.

Answer (score 0):

`params` always come in as Strings, so you need to do something to convert the input to an actual list. You can do this with `grails.converters.JSON.parse(params.listThing)`.

Comment: `println params.listThing` prints `null` and giving it to the JSON parser makes a null pointer exception.