# Grails: where does request.JSON come from, and how do I put things there with jQuery's .ajax() or .post()?

Tags: jquery, json, grails, curl, postdata

I have a controller that takes some json in the *?request body?* and does awesome things with it:

```
def myController(){
  def myAction(){
    println "Here is request.JSON: ${request.JSON as JSON}"
    println "Here is params: $params"
    //do awesome stuff with request.JSON only
    return
  }
}
```

So I can hit this with cURL like so:

```
curl -i -H "content-type: application/json" -d "{\"someVariable\":\"Absolutely\"}"
```

And my grails controller prints:

```
Here is request.JSON: {"someVariable":"Absolutely"}
Here is params: [controller:'myController', action:'myAction']
```

So far so good, but when I try to do this with jQuery it goes in params!!!

Having read these two questions:
[Setting the POST-body to a JSON object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857382/setting-the-post-body-to-a-json-object-with-jquery)

[jQuery posting valid json in request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159701/jquery-posting-valid-json-in-request-body)

My best guess for how to write the .js is:

```
var sendMe = {"someVariable":"Absolutely"}
$.ajax({
  url: '/myController/myAction',
  type: 'POST',
  processData: false,
  data: JSON.stringify(sendMe),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {

  },
  error: function(request, status, error) {

  }                     
});
```

But when I do this my controller prints:

```
Here is request.JSON: {}
Here is params: [{"someVariable":"Absolutely"}:, controller:'myController', action:'myAction']
```

I must be doing something wrong with jQuery.

UPDATE: looks like this idiot was actually having the same problem: [How to get at JSON in grails 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863874/how-to-get-at-json-in-grails-2-0) but instead of confronting the jQuery issue he just used cURL and the reqeust.JSON thing.  What a lazy guy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have the same trouble like you few days ago.

For me - the solution was to use `jQuery.ajaxSetup` to set the default value for ajax content type.

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    });
}
```

With this you could use `$.ajax` or `$.post` to transfer your JSON to the controller and use it like that:

```
def yourJSON = request.JSON
```

I dont't know why the 'contentType' option within `$.ajax` and `$.post` was ignored during my tests.

Answer (score 5):

Had a similar problem also but didn't need to use ajaxSetup, just needed to set contentType:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/api/bar"
  data: JSON.stringify({a:true}),
  contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(){
    console.log("args: %o", arguments);
  }
});
```

Comment: better answer imo